# Knapsack with non-overlapping rectangles

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation

Given a large rectangle and a set $S$ of small rectangles each with a value $v_i$. My problem is to find a collection of rectangles $T\subseteq S$ to put in the large rectangle so as to maximize the overall value $\sum_{i\in T}v_i$, subject to the constraint that the selected small rectangles cannot overlap with each other.

I suppose the problem is NP-hard.  Can we design an approximation algorithm (PTAS or constant-factor approximation ratio) approaching the optimum?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/295986/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/89738/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known as [maximum disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_disjoint_set).  In your case, assuming the rectangles are parallel to the axes, the problem is [maximum disjoint set for axis-parallel rectangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_disjoint_set#Axis-parallel_rectangles:_Logarithmic-factor_approximation).  The problem is indeed NP-hard, but Wikipedia has an approximation algorithm with an approximation ratio of $O(\log \log n)$ if all values $v_i$ are the same, or approximation ratio $O(\log n/\log \log n)$ for the general case where the values may differ for each rectangle.  You can check out the citations there to find an entry point to the research literature.

I have not been able to find any lower bounds on what approximation ratio is achievable, so as far as I can tell, it is an open problem whether you can achieve a constant-factor approximation ratio for this problem.

If you're willing to relax the running time requirement, there is a recent result achieving an approximation ratio $1+\epsilon$, at the cost that the running time becomes larger than polynomial, namely, $2^{\text{poly}(\log \log n/\epsilon)}$.  See arXiv:1307.1774 and arXiv:1608.0027.

In the case where none of the small rectangles are too small (i.e., each small rectangle has an edge whose length is at least a constant fraction of the length of corresponding edge of the large rectangle), this problem has a PTAS, i.e., $1+\epsilon$ approximation ratio is achievable.  See arXiv:1703.04758.